# How can I replace the (unsigned) bootloader in Debian with the one from Ubuntu to make it bootable one a Secure Boot-enabled device?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, boot-loader, uefi, secure-boot

**Ubuntu** 16.04 *boots fine* on my *UEFI* pc with *secure boot* turned ***ON***

**Debian** 8.6 *doesn't* because its bootloader *isn't signed*

How can I *replace the bootloader* that is present in Debian with the one found in Ubuntu so that it boots with the aforementioned situation?

And even if it (Debian) boots successfully in *live environment*,

What can I do to make sure it continues to do so after it's *installed*?

Comment: First. search in your bios/uefi options, and see maybe you can disable secure boot.
second. maybe its available with your bios/uefi updates. so update your bios/uefi if it help.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I wanna make the Debian iso secure-boot bootable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is old, but since it's still unanswered, and this was a question I had, I figured I'd share what I'd found in my own searches.

https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#using_signed

I can't give detailed instructions as I never followed through with making my Debian live usb Secure Boot enabled, but this site should help point you in the right direction and help you decide if you actually want to do it at all. Afterall, Secure Boot imposes restrictions you may not have anticipated.